# Is it correct to use "I have something on hold"?

Tags: phrases, expressions, word-usage

For example, some people have offered me price, and I am waiting for last person

so I tell him

Can you offer your price quickly? Because *I have some offers on hold*, that I have to reply to those people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can say "on hold" here, yes.

You can also use "at hand" or any other expression that conveys you have offers lying around that are pending.

Side note: I'd suggest `s/that I have to reply to [...]/and I have to reply to [...]/`.

Comment: *Handy* means useful; *at hand* means near by. Neither is a synonym for pending.

Comment: You wouldn't say "I have some offers handy".